# How to adapt the standard react-notification-system example to a fluxible project

Tags: reactjs, reactjs-flux, fluxible

I'm trying to use this component https://github.com/igorprado/react-notification-system in a standard fluxible project and am looking for guidance on how to adapt the sample code into an es6 style class.

Here's the original sample code:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var NotificationSystem = require('react-notification-system');

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  _notificationSystem: null,

  _addNotification: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this._notificationSystem.addNotification({
      message: 'Notification message',
      level: 'success'
    });
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this._notificationSystem = this.refs.notificationSystem;
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this._addNotification}>Add notification</button>
        <NotificationSystem ref="notificationSystem" />
      </div>
      );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement(MyComponent),
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

And here's my attempt to add it to a fluxible application component, should I add the notificationSystem object into state?  Is using componentDidMount always reliable if I'm connecting to stores?  How should I trigger the notification from an action - should I update a notificationStore that triggers the component or act on the component directly somehow from the action itself?

```
class Application extends React.Component {

    //constructor(props) {
    //    super(props);
    //    this.state = {
    //        notificationSystem: this.refs.notificationSystem
    //    };
    //}

    addNotification(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.notificationSystem.addNotification({
            message: 'Notification message',
            level: 'success'
        });
    }

    render() {
        var Handler = this.props.currentRoute.get('handler');

        return (
            <div>
                <Nav currentRoute={this.props.currentRoute} links={pages} />
                <div className="main">
                    <Handler />
                </div>
                <NotificationSystem ref="notificationSystem" />
            </div>
        );
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.state.notificationSystem = this.refs.notificationSystem;
    }

    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        const newProps = this.props;
        if (newProps.pageTitle === prevProps.pageTitle) {
            return;
        }
        document.title = newProps.pageTitle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store it on a property of your Application:

```
class Application extends React.Component {

    //constructor(props) {
    //    super(props);
    //    this.state = {
    //        notificationSystem: this.refs.notificationSystem
    //    };
    //}

    notificationSystem = null;

    componentDidMount() {
        this.notificationSystem = this.refs.notificationSystem;
    }

    addNotification(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.notificationSystem.addNotification({
            message: 'Notification message',
            level: 'success'
        });
    }
```

Or if you want a more complete example using flux pattern:

This answer was based on: https://github.com/igorprado/react-notification-system/issues/29#issuecomment-157219303

**React component that will trigger the notification:**

```
_saveFileStart() {
    this.props.flux.getActions('notification').info({
      title: 'Saving file',
      message: 'Please wait until your file is saved...',
      position: 'tc',
      autoDismiss: 0,
      dismissible: false
    });
  }
...
render() {
    <button onClick={ this._saveFileStart.bind(this) }>Save file</button>
}
```

**Notification actions, there is a `.info()` alias to trigger notifications with level `info`**

```
constructor() {
    this.generateActions('add', 'remove', 'success', 'error', 'warning', 'info');
}
```

(I'm using the alt generator to generate the `add` action, `remove` and some aliases)

**Notification store**

```
constructor() {
    this.bindActions(this.alt.getActions('notification'));

    this.state = {
      notification: null,
      intent: null
    };
  }
...
  onInfo(notification) {
    return this._add(notification, 'info');
  }
...
  _add(notification, level) {
    if (!notification) return false;
    if (level) notification.level = level;
    return this.setState({ notification, intent: 'add' });
  }
```

**React component that will render the Notification component on a top level HTML element**

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { flux } = this.props;
    flux.getStore('notification').listen(this._handleNotificationChange);
}
...
  _handleNotificationChange = ({ notification, intent }) => {
    if (intent === 'add') {
      this.refs.notifications.addNotification(notification);
    }
  };
...
  render() {
    return <ReactNotificationSystem ref='notifications' />;
  }
```

This answer was based on: https://github.com/igorprado/react-notification-system/issues/29#issuecomment-157219303

Comment: Hi Igor, I follow the simple use case and more complex use cases in the repo and everytime I try to invoke `addNotification` method on `NotificationSystem`, I get `TypeError: addNotification is not a function`. I follow exactly the recommended example. Thoughts where I might be doing wrong? Thanks!